# How can I get DataLabels type in Chart?

Tags: c#, charts, powerpoint, office-interop

I am trying to apply same DataLabels format for Series object as it is on another chart, so I'm stuck on getting Type of DataLabels in Series to apply using method:

```
Series._ApplyDataLabels(XlDataLabelsType)
```

So is there any possibility to GET XlDataLabelsType from existing chart?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is query the various `Show` properies of the `DataLabel` object. For example:

```
Series ser = chart.SeriesCollection[1];
DataLabels dls = ser.DataLabels;
DataLabel dl = dls[1];
Debug.Print(dl.ShowValue.ToString(), dl.ShowBubbleSize.ToString());
```

These will return Boolean True/False depending on whether the option is activated or not. It should be possible to correlate this information with the type enumeration.